# unable to use HTML symbol inside php code

Tags: php, html, wordpress, title, html-entities

I have created a little code to be put inside the `<title>` tags, of my Wordpress website, to echo a certain title depending on which page the visitor is. Here's the code:

```
<title>
    <?php if ( is_page('144')) { bloginfo('name'); } else { wp_title(''); bloginfo('name'); } ?>
</title>
```

Now I want to put a space or a vertical bar ( | ) in between the Page Title and the Blog Name, inside the php code, but I am unable to do so. I tried using `&nbsp;` and `&#124;` like this:

```
<title>
    <?php if ( is_page('144')) { bloginfo('name'); } else { wp_title('');&#124;bloginfo('name'); } ?>
</title>
```

but it returns an error saying that `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&'`.

I was wondering if there's any solution to this problem, looking forward to hear from the experts, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Use `echo "|"` instead of `&#124`

Answer (score 2):

Your recieving this error because you are not `echoing` the `space` or `pipe`:

```
<title><?php
if ( is_page('144')) { 
    bloginfo('name');
} else {
    wp_title('');
    echo '|';
    bloginfo('name'); 
}
?></title>
```

Alternatively, you could use the `get_` prefix that wordpress uses and concatenate the string like so:

```
echo get_the_title().'|'.get_bloginfo('name');
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, your solution worked. And thanks to everybody else who replied. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just one little problem which persists and because of which I created this code. I want the divider to be hidden, in the titlem if we're on the page with ID: 144 but currently the divider is appearing in the title of the page with ID: 144. Is there any way to hide it we're on a certain page?

Comment: If i'm understanding your question correctly, you might try `if(!is_page('144'))`, which would show the `|` on all pages **except** page 144

Comment: I tried using "if(!is_page('144'))" instead of "if ( is_page('144'))" but now the same title is appearing through out all the pages i.e. only "bloginfo('name');" is appearing in the title.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
  echo '|';
```

You need to echo if you want to output text

Answer (score 1):

Everything within the `<?php .... ?>` has to be valid PHP code.  `&nbsp;` and `&#124;` is HTML, not PHP. If you want to write HTML in the middle, you have to end the PHP segment with `?>` and start again with `<?php` afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use echo or print.

```
<title> <?php if ( is_page('144')) {  bloginfo('name'); } else {  wp_title(''); echo '&#124'; bloginfo('name'); } ?> </title>
```

Comment: wp_title() and bloginfo() don't return strings, so you can't chain them together like that.

Comment: @naomik - Changed code. IMHO it is good practice not to output things like this directly in functions. Functions that process data should return data and then it should be printed out by the caller.

Comment: Revent, that's how shitty wordpress is; blame them, not me :)